# Parameterization entity with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create an entity to parameterize values ​​of business rules, I thought of something like Name, Type and Value (s), eg:

Name: Add in the price of the imported product

Type: Value (Double)

Value: 20

That would be used in a rule to add 20% to the price of the imported product. But I have several situations with value as String, Boolean or multi-valued. 
I thought of something like this:

```
 @NotEmpty
 private String name;

//Enum with possible types (Text, Value, Boolean, etc)
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Enumeration(enumClass = ParameterType.class)
 private ParameterType type;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "value")
 private List<ParameterValue> values;
```

The ParameterValue entity, how could I implement it, since value(s) ​​can be of various types (Double, String, Boolean, etc)?

This not works:

```
public class ParameterValue  {


 private Object value;

}
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: br.entity.admin.ParameterValue.value type: object"}}

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your column in the database.
For example if you use `enum` in `MySQL`. It can be:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ParameterType type;
```

where `ParameterValue` is

```
public enum ParameterValue  {
   Text, Value, Boolean
}
```

Comment: ParameterValue will have a column to record a value like 20 or TRUE, or "Some Text", etc., not the Enum values. I think i'm not clear in my question, sorry. A can use VARCHAR and convert the value, but i'm looking for something better.